# How to I add multiple distinct JSON objects into seperate lists in WinJS app?

Tags: windows, windows-8, winjs

I am trying to create a grid app with various sections and each section is being fetched to a specific listview however I have encountered a problem where you can only have one listview covering the entire page in order to properly horizontally scroll the objects inside the list which means there's no room for another one. This is the code I am using right now:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23windows8&rpp=100}).then(

            function (response) {
                var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText.toString());
                var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(json.result);
                gridView1.winControl.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;

                //gridView1 is ID of listview 

            }
```

With the above code  I can easily show grids of objects containing result array and then bind em to the list. However now I want multiple similar listviews for different URLs that are displayed like the one shown as default interface in WinJS grid app.

To be more clear, this is what I want - Twitter usernames in first section of grid by using Twitter API URL1 and then I want twitter search results in adjacent grid so I have to use another listview  b using URL2.

How do I find a fix for this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to group data, or how to have multiple list views sxs?

Comment: Yeah grouping data would work. Infact, I'd want to replicate the group data in listview sample but how do I do that? Different URLs need different listview, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, coming up with what all of the disparate items from the different lists have in common and projecting your data up to a single grouped list is one option. You might not want to give up on what you were trying to do though. If you put multiple ListViews on a page wrapped in a flexbox, you shouldn't have any trouble with scrolling. If you look at my [codeSHOW](http://aka.ms/codeshowapp) app at the ListView demo, you'll see that I have the rough equivalent. Windows is actually really smart about the way it handles the panning.

** **EDIT** **

Here's a rough example of what I'm talking about. Again, you can find a working example of this in the ListView demo of [codeSHOW](http://aka.ms/codeshowapp).

```
<!-- HTML snippet -->
<div class="hub">
  <div>
    <div id="list1" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="list2" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="list3" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
  </div>
</div>

/* CSS snippet */
.hub {
  display:-ms-flexbox; /* this will lay the lists out horizontally */
  overflow-x:auto; /* set the flexbox to scroll its overflow */
}

/* select each of the sections */
.hub > div {
  padding-right:80px; /* 80px of space between "sections" */
}

/* choose whatever sizes you want for your list views. You may want to make them wide
enough that they don't scroll because it can get a little awkward to have scrolling
within scrolling */
[data-win-control=WinJS.UI.ListView] {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate on "If you put multiple ListViews on a page wrapped in a flexbox, you shouldn't have any trouble with scrolling". You want me to make the 2 list views child of the a CSS flexbox control? Can you provide a quick example please (2 sampled listbox data + flexbox)? Because I did try and it isn't really working.  There's nothing related to it atm on the interwebz, will help a lot of people.

Comment: Gotcha. absolute genius :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by aggregating the result set into a single data source.

You can either do this through splurging your data into a `WinJS.Binding.List` that's been set up with a grouping function, and attribute your data in such a way that you know how to group them. An example of the grouping of a `WinJS.Binding.List` can be found in the "Grid" Template that you find in Visual Studio when doing File/New/Project.

Or, you can build your own data `VirtualizedDataSource` - there is a great tutorial for this on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770849.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I did see the sample you mentioned - it's working with local images though which solves most of the problems. Any VirtualizedDataSource sample with json/xml data?

Comment: It's not working with images; it's working with data which enumerates the images in a JSON result that can be used to expose that datasource. (See section 6.3)

Comment: Alright, this is definitely not the one I saw, my bad. Will work on it and let you know the results, thanks.

Comment: hey, any example you could find where two or more xml/json URLs are being used for grid apps? Or even an example of binding multiple JSON /XML urls into single data source?