# WinJS Listview Groups with different dataSources?

Tags: listview, winjs

we need a `ListView` for our `Win8` App with `GroupedItems.`
No Problem at all, but we need different `dataSources` for each group.

e.g. we need three groups:

1. Group with Buttons / fixed Data
2. Group with categories / Data via xhr (e.g. `/categories.php?limit=10`)
3. Group with articles / Data via xhr / incrental loading (e.g. `/articles.php?limit=none&offset=50&start=0`)

THANKS in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge your data into one dataSource, and then group based on that information. This can be done either through managing a `WinJS.Binding.List` and just placing the data into it w/ a grouping function, or if you want to get very advanced, use a `VirtualizedDataSource`. My answer in the question below links to the appropriate place for that information.

[How to I add multiple distinct JSON objects into seperate lists in WinJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327499/how-to-i-add-multiple-distinct-json-objects-into-seperate-lists-in-winjs-app/14343003#14343003)